# There has been an error processing your request after importing "theme sql file" to magento2 site

Tags: magento2

I have following error after importing "demo data sql file of theme" in magento 2. I don't know how to resolve this issue. Please help me.

There has been an error processing your request
Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_GoogleShoppingAds schema: code version - 3.0.1, database version - 4.0.1
Magento_GoogleShoppingAds data: code version - 3.0.1, database version - 4.0.1
Amazon_Core schema: code version - 3.4.1, database version - 3.4.1-p3
Amazon_Core data: code version - 3.4.1, database version - 3.4.1-p3
Amazon_Login schema: code version - 3.4.1, database version - 3.4.1-p3
Amazon_Login data: code version - 3.4.1, database version - 3.4.1-p3
Amazon_Payment schema: code version - 3.4.1, database version - 3.4.1-p3
Amazon_Payment data: code version - 3.4.1, database version - 3.4.1-p3
Dotdigitalgroup_Email schema: code version - 4.4.0, database version - 4.4.1
Dotdigitalgroup_Email data: code version - 4.4.0, database version - 4.4.1
Dotdigitalgroup_Chat schema: code version - 1.0.1, database version - 1.0.1-p1
Dotdigitalgroup_Chat data: code version - 1.0.1, database version - 1.0.1-p1
Klarna_Core schema: code version - 5.2.3, database version - 5.3.2
Klarna_Core data: code version - 5.2.3, database version - 5.3.2
Klarna_Ordermanagement schema: code version - 5.0.7, database version - 5.1.1
Klarna_Ordermanagement data: code version - 5.0.7, database version - 5.1.1
Klarna_Kp schema: code version - 6.4.0, database version - 6.5.3
Klarna_Kp data: code version - 6.4.0, database version - 6.5.3
Error log record number: 0fe30834a991ec325a4f5b8a3e7a1367fe668b891cc6aaa78e400438f4793b32

Comment: Please run "compoer install" command under your Magento project directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I re-installed latest magneto version then problem solved as this problem was due to older version(2.3) of magento 2.